# as3 Quadtree being slow

Tags: actionscript-3, quadtree

This is my quadtree class, but i haven't added the collision detection yet, in all the examples online they can get 500 + at 60 fps with collision detection but my one only running at 20 fps without collision detection.

I'm following this tutorial http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-use-quadtrees-to-detect-likely-collisions-in-2d-space--gamedev-374 which is java but im using as3

```
public class Quadtree extends Entity
{
    private var Max_objects:int = 1;
    private var Max_levels:int = 5;

    private var level:int;
    private var objects:Vector.<Rectangle>;
    public var rectangle:Rectangle;
    public var Quadtree_list:Vector.<Quadtree>;

    public function Quadtree(tmp_level:int , tmp_rec:Rectangle) 
    {
        level = tmp_level;
        objects = new Vector.<Rectangle>();
        rectangle = tmp_rec;
        Quadtree_list = new Vector.<Quadtree>();
        Quadtree_list.length = 3;

    }

     public function clear():void
     {
        objects.length = 0;
        for (var i:Number = 0; i < Quadtree_list.length ; i++)
        {
            if (Quadtree_list[i] != null)
            {
                Quadtree_list[i].clear();
                world.remove(Quadtree_list[i]);
                Quadtree_list[i] = null;

            }
        }
     }

    public function split():void
    {
        var subWidth:int = rectangle.width / 2;
        var subHeight:int = rectangle.height / 2;
        var xx:int = rectangle.x;
        var yy:int = rectangle.y;

        Base._world.add(Quadtree_list[0] = new Quadtree(level + 1, new Rectangle(xx + subWidth, yy, subWidth, subHeight)));
        Base._world.add(Quadtree_list[1] = new Quadtree(level+1,new Rectangle(xx ,yy,subWidth,subHeight)));
        Base._world.add(Quadtree_list[2] = new Quadtree(level+1,new Rectangle(xx,yy + subHeight,subWidth,subHeight)));
        Base._world.add(Quadtree_list[3] = new Quadtree(level+1,new Rectangle(xx + subWidth,yy + subHeight,subWidth,subHeight)));
    }

    /*
     * Determine which node the object belongs to. -1 means
     * object cannot completely fit within a child node and is part
     * of the parent node
     */
    public function get_index(tmp_rect:Rectangle):Number
    {
        var index:int = -1;
        var verticalMidpoint:Number = rectangle.x + (rectangle.width / 2);
        var horizontalMidpoint:Number = rectangle.y + (rectangle.height / 2);

        // Object can completely fit within the top quadrants
        var topQuadrant:Boolean = (tmp_rect.y < horizontalMidpoint && tmp_rect.y + tmp_rect.height < horizontalMidpoint);
         // Object can completely fit within the bottom quadrants
        var bottomQuadrant:Boolean = (tmp_rect.y > horizontalMidpoint);

         // Object can completely fit within the left quadrants
         if (tmp_rect.x < verticalMidpoint && tmp_rect.x + tmp_rect.width < verticalMidpoint)
         {
             if (topQuadrant)
             {
                 index = 1;
             }
             else if (bottomQuadrant)
             {
                 index = 2;
             }
         }
         else 
         // Object can completely fit within the right quadrants
         if (tmp_rect.x > verticalMidpoint)
         {
             if (topQuadrant)
             {
                 index = 0;
             }
             else if (bottomQuadrant)
             {
                 index = 3;
             }
         }
         return index;
    }

    /*
     * Insert the object into the quadtree. If the node
     * exceeds the capacity, it will split and add all
     * objects to their corresponding nodes.
     */
    public function insert(tmp_rect:Rectangle):void
    {

        if (Quadtree_list[0] != null)
        {
            var index:int = get_index(tmp_rect);
            if (index != -1)
            {
                Quadtree_list[index].insert(tmp_rect)
                return;
            }
        }

        objects.push(tmp_rect);

        if (objects.length > Max_objects && level < Max_levels)
        {
            if (Quadtree_list[0] == null)
            {
                split(); 
            }
            var i:int = 0;
            while (i < objects.length)
            {
                var indexx:int = get_index(objects[i]);
                if (indexx != -1)
                {
                    Quadtree_list[indexx].insert(objects[i]);
                    objects.splice(i, 1);
                }
                else 
                {
                    i++;
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Can you see why it's not performing very well?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say for certain without seeing exactly how you're using it.  Plus it extends Entity which could be doing ...anything :)

I'm not an expert on Quadtrees either, but if you're calling split() a lot, it looks like it could end up being taxing - lots of instantiation calls to new Quadtree and new Rectangle.  If this is indeed a bottleneck, you could look into instantiating one rectangle instance that you just pass around.  Same with Quadtree.  Or use object pooling so you're at least recycling instead of creating new things like crazy.

I hope that helps :)